# Header style using the memoir class

Tags: sectioning, memoir

Is it possible to reproduce the below heading style using the memoir builtin header style utilities?

[image]

[image]

Comment: ...most likely. That's an answer as far as I can tell. :)

Comment: I don't quite understand the numbering scheme used

Comment: It is Chapter for the left page and Section in the right page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% don't convert titles to upper case in header
\nouppercaseheads
% define what goes where in the header
% chapter into \leftmark, number shown, nothing before the
% number and a dot and space after it
\createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. }
% section into \rightmark, number shown, nothing before the
% number and just a space after it
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{ }
% define new pagestyle
\makepagestyle{myheadings}
% head for even numbered pages, chapter title on the left with
% preferred font and size, center and right side of header are empty
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\textit{\small\leftmark}}{}{}
% head for odd numbered pages, left side and center of header
% are empty, section title on the right with preferred font and size
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{}{}{\textit{\small\rightmark}}
% set pagestyle
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Something about lipsum}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

There are also `\makeevenfoot` and `\makeoddfoot` for the footline.
More details can be found in section 7.3 of the memoir manual.

Comment: Mike, do I have to recreate the heather again once I transition from back matter to mainmatter environment?

Comment: @lf_araujo I think you meant from mainmatter to backmatter. After `\backmatter` chapters and section are no longer numbered by default. So there are no numbers in the header too, But besides that, they are the same font and size.